# Read and edit onlinefiles with java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I want to read and write a text document which i upload in "one drive" or "google drive" in java.

```
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String line;
        URL url = new URL("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JLRmW7eaXHyyoPdNCyNN7AHWzKWaAPWgL84sxHUB7dQ/edit");
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
}
```

With this code i only read the HTML documentation and thats not helpful.
In this text are some IPs from servers I have to connect with clients.
Note that i want to access this file from a java program, not an android app. 
As i researched, the available google drive apis are not quite suited for java implementation, 
since they are build for android solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> the available google drive apis are not quite suited for java implementation

Google APIs support Java. Android is Java, so the API (classes, methods you need to call, etc.) is the same on either platform.

The Drive API is part of the Google API Client Library. Here is a great overview:

[Google API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2)

A [Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2) with instructions on getting set up and some [Examples](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples).

The [drive-cmdline-sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/drive-cmdline-sample) project would be a good place to start. There is a downloadFile method that looks like it will get the source file:

```
/** Downloads a file using either resumable or direct media download. */
private static void downloadFile(boolean useDirectDownload, File uploadedFile)
  throws IOException {
  // create parent directory (if necessary)
  java.io.File parentDir = new java.io.File(DIR_FOR_DOWNLOADS);
  if (!parentDir.exists() && !parentDir.mkdirs()) {
     throw new IOException("Unable to create parent directory");
  }
  OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(parentDir, uploadedFile.getTitle()));

  MediaHttpDownloader downloader =
    new MediaHttpDownloader(httpTransport, drive.getRequestFactory().getInitializer());
  downloader.setDirectDownloadEnabled(useDirectDownload);
  downloader.setProgressListener(new FileDownloadProgressListener());
  downloader.download(new GenericUrl(uploadedFile.getDownloadUrl()), out);
}
```